# 2 Android resources with same name but different image

Tags: android, android-drawable

I used the Android Studio built-in function to create a new DrawerActivity.

This created the default DrawerLayout with its own default icons, and it also created `res/values/drawable.xml` :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="ic_menu_camera" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
</resources>
```

Actually, if I use these items in my Drawer, the former is light-grey and point to the right whereas the latter is black and point to the left :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
    android:title="Manage"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_manage2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
    android:title="Other Manage"/>
```

But if I Ctrl+click my resources, they both point to the former, which path is `"E:\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\platforms\android-25\data\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_menu_manage.png"`.

**EDIT : I figured it out, turned out that the former points to drawable-ldpi and the latter to drawable-hdpi. My questions remain exactly the same :**

- Why this behaviour ? Does it come from Android or from something in my code ?
- What is this drawable.xml file ? Shoud I use it with all my drawables ?
- Where can I find documentation about it (tried on google with no success) ?

Comment: too many questions for a single question.

Comment: I think they are all somehow related. Do you really think I should copy-paste the exacte same post 4 times with each question ?